# Undefined index & Invalid argument supplied for foreach() + form

Tags: php

for some reason I keep getting following errors:

-- Undefined index: remove on line 5

-- Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 6

Do you have any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thank you :)

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['remove_yes'])){    
    echo $_POST['remove'];
    foreach($_POST['remove'] as $item){         
      echo  ('You have just removed location id: '.$item . '<br         />');             
    }                   
  }  
  elseif(isset($_POST['remove_no'])){ 
    echo 'No data removed!';        
  }
  ?>                 
  <form method="post">
  <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit_remove"     value="Remove">
  <input type="checkbox" name="remove[a]">
  <input type="checkbox" name="remove[b]">
  </form>    
  <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit_remove'])){    //confirmation
  ?>            
  <form method="post">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Do you want to really remove data?</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value = "Yes" name = "remove_yes"></td>
        <td><input type ="submit" value = "No" name="remove_no"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>            
  </form>            
  <?php
  }
 ?>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$_POST['remove']`  is an array

Comment: yes it is supposed to be

Comment: Because you have 2 different forms.

Comment: you need to check if `$_POST['remove']` is also set.

Comment: and you need ist form's value into second from. right

Comment: and this is an out of scope issue. Many things wrong here. The left hand doesn't know what the right hand is doing. The "hands" here being the "forms" and their elements.

Comment: Fred -ii- what else is wrong?

Comment: your error means that `$_POST['remove']` doesn't exist. Since you are not checking if  `$_POST['remove']` is set you get this error whenever your form is not populating the values for `$_POST['remove']`

Comment: You'd be best to either use ajax/jQuery or sessions if you want one form to talk to the other. Again; "out of scope".

Comment: I need to use just php..
so if I understand it I need to put it in 1 form and also check if remove is set?

Comment: yes, either use "one" form or use sessions if you want to pass data to any other pages. The easiest solution would be "one" form.

Comment: you can store values into hidden field inside the second form something like `<?php

  if(is_array($_POST['remove'])){ 
   foreach ($_POST['remove'] as $key => $value) {
   ?>
   <input type="hidden" name="remove[]" value="<?=$value?>">
   <?php 
   }
   # code...
  }
  ?>`

Answer (score 0):

you just have to handle a single tag form ;)

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['remove_yes'])){    
    foreach($_POST['remove'] as $key =>$item){         
    echo  ('You have just removed location id: '.$key . '<br         />');      

    }                   
    }  
    elseif(isset($_POST['remove_no'])){ 
    echo 'No data removed!';        
    }
    ?>                 
    <form method="post">
        <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit_remove"     value="Remove">
        a<input type="checkbox" <?=($_POST['remove']['a']=='on')?'checked="checked"': ''?> name="remove[a]">
                b<input type="checkbox" <?=($_POST['remove']['b']=='on')?'checked="checked"': ''?> name="remove[b]">
                <?php
                if(isset($_POST['submit_remove'])){ 
                //confirmation
                ?>            
                <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Do you want to really remove data?</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>yes
                    <input type="submit" value="Yes" name="remove_yes">
                </td>
                <td>NO<input type ="submit" value="No" name="remove_no"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>            
    </form>            
    <?php
    }
    ?>  
</body></html>
```